# React native - Material Top Tabs Navigator with swipe list view swipe inside the tab

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation, react-navigation-top-tabs

I'm using [react navigation 5.x material top tabs navigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/5.x/material-top-tab-navigator) in my app with two tabs,
Inside of both the tabs I have [swipe list view component](https://github.com/jemise111/react-native-swipe-list-view).

I want to be able to swipe the rows on the list view but when I try to swipe them the tab is also gets swiped.

I can cancel the swipe on the tabs for good, but I want it to be enabled when the user will swipe outside of the dynamic list.

How can I do that? thanks for the help

Comment: Have u figured this out? Have the same issue

Comment: Unfortunately not..

Comment: Did you find a solution yet?

Comment: No, I left this matter, maybe I will try in the future but don't count on it

Answer (score 1):

I'm using @react-navigation v6.

on `SwipeListView` implement

```
  onTouchStart={({nativeEvent: {locationX: x}}) => {
    if (x > TAB_SWIPE_OFFSET &&
      x < Dimensions.get('screen').width - TAB_SWIPE_OFFSET
    ) {
      navigation.setOptions({swipeEnabled: false});
    } else {
      navigation.setOptions({swipeEnabled: true});
    }
  }}

  onTouchEnd={() => navigation.setOptions({swipeEnabled: true})}
```